# why can't I convert all words to uppercase C

Tags: c++, c, uppercase, capitalize

I don't know why input capital letters in string are changed to random code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define length 100
int main()
{
   int count;
   char word[length];
   printf("Please input your word =");
   scanf("%s", &word);
   count=strlen(word);
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<=count;i++)
   {
        if(word[i]>=97||word[i]<=122)
        {
           word[i]+= -32;
        }
        printf(" %c",word[i]);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please use toupper - http://linux.die.net/man/3/toupper

Comment: In  "if(word[i]>=97||word[i]<=122)" - your condition is true for every value.

Comment: If you tagged this as C++, why is your code 'C'?  Turning a word to upper case in C++ is a one-line algorithm call.  Second, your loop has a bug -- it has `i` going up to `<=count`.  Therefore you're messing around with the null terminator when you shouldn't be.

Comment: use `word[i] >= 'a' && word[i] <= 'z'` instead

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
if(word[i]>=97||word[i]<=122)
```

To:

```
if(word[i]>=97 && word[i]<=122)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using AND operator instead of OR operator in condition.

```
if(word[i]>=97 && word[i]<=122)    //to specify small character region's upper AND lower bound
```

and may be try using

```
word[i] -= 32; //for simplicity
```

Answer (score 0):

|| -------》 &&

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define length 100
int main()
 {
    int count;
    char word[length];
    printf("Please input your word =");
    scanf("%s", word);
    count=strlen(word);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
       {
           if(word[i]>=97&&word[i]<=122)
             {
                word[i]+= -32;
             }
           printf(" %c",word[i]);
  }
    return 0;
}
```